# How many friends does Tiffany have?

Tags: logical-deduction, combinatorics

Tiffany has 14 classmates. This means that there are a total of 15 students in the class. All of her 14 classmates have a different number of friends in the class. Tiffany, however, may have the same number of friends as another classmate does.

How many friends does Tiffany have ? (If A is a friend of B, then B is a friend of A.)

Comment: Can you also provide the source of this puzzle if it is not yours?

Comment: Why do you want to know?

Comment: Because otherwise it [could be considered plagiarism, according to site policy](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/a-policy-on-plagiarism)

Comment: @justhalf , I want to solve this question myself  before needing to read your answer. Now, if there are 15 students total in the class and each one has a different number of friends then the number of friends the classmates have are 0, 1, 2, 3....14. But, if one classmate  has 0 friends , then it is not possible for another classmate to have 14 friends. Therefore , in a class of 15, my understanding is that it is not possible for each classmate to have a different number of friends . What am I missing ?

Comment: What you are missing is that Tiffany is not required to have different number of friends in the class. Since only Tiffany's classmates have different number of friends. @HemantAgarwal

Comment: The question has now been edited by me and my comment above and justhalf's reply to it is no longer needed to understand the question .

Comment: How does this address the reason why it got locked?

Comment: @Nautilus , this question was locked before I commented .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 15 people in the class, and the number of friends can only go from 0 to 14, and if there is someone with 0 friends, there will be no one with 14 friends. So at most there are 14 distinct number of friends, and it is either 0-13 or 1-14. And note that if Tiffany's 14 classmates have 0-13 number friends, we can change that to 1-14 simply by making the one with 0 friend to be friends with those who had 7-13 friends (making those to have 8-14 friends, and the one who had 0 friend to have 7 friends, not changing those with 1-6 friends, so we have 1-14). Since this doesn't affect the number of friends Tiffany has, we can assume that it is the case of 1-14 number of friends that is happening here (the same reasoning below can work with 0-13).

Let the 14 friends be called C1, C2, ..., C14, according to the number of friends they have. So C1 has 1 friend, C2 has 2 friends, and so on. So we have Tiffany + C1-C14 (should we call it "Tiffany and the 14 C's"?)

Now notice that:

- The one with 14 friends (C14) should be friends with everyone else, including Tiffany. Now this makes the one with only one friend (C1) not friend with Tiffany, since C1 is already friend with C14 and C1 only has one friend. From here we know that Tiffany is friend with C14, and not with C1.
- The one with 13 friends (C13) should be friends with everyone else except C1. Now this makes the one with two friends (C2) not friend with Tiffany, since C2 is already friends with C14 and C13. From here we know that Tiffany is friend with C13, and not with C2.
- Continuing the pattern of pairing off C(N) with C(15-N), we have C14, C13, C12, C11, C10, C9, and C8 as Tiffany's friends. And the rest (C1, C2, ..., C7) are not friends with Tiffany.
- So

  > Tiffany has **7 friends**.

Comment: Um. I may be missing something, but what is stopping Tiffany from being C14?

Comment: @Xenocacia Tiffany is not in the C1 to C14 set.

Comment: Yeah, like Weijun said, the set of people here is Tiffany + C1-C14 (her 14 classmates, as written in the question). I should have made this clearer. I've edited my answer to clarify that.